Change Background Image by section ID on Long Scrolling Page
I am adapting an HTML5UP template (Astral: https://html5up.net/astral), and I am running into a problem. I would like the background image to change with each ID, but whenever I attempt to apply solutions either with JavaScript or CSS, it modifies the background of that particular section (which I don't want to change) instead of the background of the entire page. The demo project can be found here: https://madisonpjones.com/projects/nwp
You can see an example of the error on this page:
https://madisonpjones.com/projects/nwp/#about
The background of the section should appear like this:
https://madisonpjones.com/projects/nwp/#visualize
In other words, I would like to maintain the white background for the section, changing the actual background.
The solution I have been using (that produces the error) was this:
  <script>
// Change background image using pure JavaScript 
   document.getElementById('about').style.backgroundImage = 
   'url("assets/css/images/overlay.png"), 
   url("assets/css/images/bg2.png"), 
   url("assets/css/images//bg.jpg")'; 
 </script>
         

For context, the Astral theme is a long scrolling page that has been modified to show sections as individual pages. I am sure this is what is creating the section-background issue, but I can't figure out how.
I have tried looking on numerous pages/forums and haven't found a workable solution. I see lots of options for changing the background on a regular site using JS or CSS, but I can't seem to make any of them work in this case. Thanks in advance for your help!

Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? -> TLDR: No.

The trouble I'm running into is that if I could figure out which part of the CSS is causing the problem, I would be able to fix it. I'm confused by the way this theme is displaying the sections over the background image, which is part of my issue. Happy to edit with whatever would be helpful.

After some debugging, the correct way to do what you want seems to be this.
In main.js, you have an array called panels[], where each page of your site has it's own element. First, add a property in each, containing the corresponding background-image.
The panels[] array seems to be populated from some framework presets, imported on line 89:
panels[id] = t;

If you don't have access to the preset, I suggest you create an object right after line 45, which is:
.on('+desktop', function() {

And there you create the object my_bgs, exactly as I suggested in my other answer:
var my_bgs = {
    // Change the values according to your needs
    about:'url("assets/css/images/bg1.png")',
    visualize:'url("assets/css/images/bg2.png")',
    approach:'url("assets/css/images/bg3.png")',
    map:'url("assets/css/images/bg4.png")',
    conclusion:'url("assets/css/images/bg5.png")',
    references:'url("assets/css/images/bg6.png")'
}

Then, right after the already mentioned line 89 (panels[id] = t;), add:
panels[id].specialstyle = my_bgs[id];

Then, on line 178-179, where you have:
if (id in panels)
    panels[id]._activate();

Change that to:
if (id in panels) {
    panels[id]._activate();
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = panels[id].specialstyle;
}

That should do it.

This looks like the exact answer. If you don't mind answering one more of my stupid questions, do you know where the panels array would be located (for me to add the properties)? I'm searching for it but can't find it. I made the edits to the main.js file you suggested.

That's no stupid question, I tried to find it myself with some trouble. I think you are using some framework, and it has some presets classes/properties/events that it just applies to every matching element it needs. So I'm pretty sure the critical line is in main.js line 89: panels[id] = t;. I've just edited the answer with an update. See if it suits your needs.

This absolutely fixed it. I will push an update to the demo site later today. This answer will be helpful to anyone who is trying to adapt one of those templates, as this is a common point of frustration. I'm so grateful for your time in working through this problem.

You've very welcome! I'm glad I could help.

By the code you submitted, it seems you are changing the background of the section (in this case, <article id="about" class="panel">, which is working as it is supposed to.
If what you want is to change the page background, instead of the section, then you should use document.body instead of document.getElementById('about').
So your code should be as:
<script>
// Change background image using pure JavaScript
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("assets/css/images/overlay.png"), url("assets/css/images/bg2.png"), url("assets/css/images//bg.jpg")'; 
</script>

EDIT:
According to the new infos provided, you could try creating an object of the styles for each ID, and set the style of the body according to which article is displayed.
I agree it might look like an ugly approach, but if you are very limited in your access to the sources, it might be the only way.
It would look something like this:
<script>
// Change background image using pure JavaScript
var id_list = {
    // Change the values according to your needs
    about:'url("assets/css/images/bg1.png")',
    visualize:'url("assets/css/images/bg2.png")',
    approach:'url("assets/css/images/bg3.png")',
    map:'url("assets/css/images/bg4.png")',
    conclusion:'url("assets/css/images/bg5.png")',
    references:'url("assets/css/images/bg6.png")'
}
for (var article_id of Object.keys(id_list)) {
    if (document.getElementById(article_id).style != 'display: none') {
        // This is the displayed article
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = id_list[article_id]; 
    }
}
</script>


Thank you! This did change the background. Unfortunately, it changed the background across all of the website, not just for the individual section/id (i.e.—the "about" page). Is there something I should change to specify that I want to get by ID but change the document body?

Do you have to do it programatically? Can't you load a specific CSS file for every page? Or you must have a unique CSS file for you whole site? For a useful answer, more information would be necessary.

Thanks for the question. It uses a a unique CSS file for the whole site. The pages are acutally one single page but displayed this way through CSS. That's what is creating the issue that I can't sort out. You could think of this as a long scrolling page where each new section would change the background of the entire site (effectively what is happening).

Actually, the same question applies to the script. The problem is I don`t know how much liberty you have to change the source code. You could always do a condition test, and change the background accordingly. It could get kind of ugly... but would work as intended.

This makes sense. Would that mean I create an event listener for change in the ID that would then run something like the script above (but with a different background linked for the relevant section)?

I just checked the link you provided, and what I see is a static HTML: scrolling does not affect the display of sections. Am I wrong? So the display of sections is activated on page loading. There must be a script where you set which article gets activated. This script should change the body background according to the activated article.

I just edited the answer suggesting a code that should work, it there is no cleaner way to do it.
